# Adding GMail-like "archive" functionality to Windows Explorer 

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-explorer

One of the things I love about GMail is the one-click ability to move files out of my inbox without throwing them out.

What's the best way to add a hook to Windows Explorer (Windows 7) to do the same for my local files? Ideally, it would be a right-click menu item (or keyboard shortcut) to move (not just copy) the files to `C:\User\USERID\Archive`, or something like that, and automatically rename conflicting files.

Comment: Probably an autohotkey script to copy/move it to an archive folder

Comment: Are you meaning e-mail within something like Outlook, or local files?

Comment: It might be worth noting that 'archiving' an email in Gmail does not actually 'move it' anywhere, it simply removes the 'inbox' _label_.

Comment: @HaydnWVN local files. w3d is right that they're not exactly comparable, but that's what it seems like.

Comment: So your question is `local files` and not at all e-mail related...